# How To Call A TextField From Different Functions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm new to swift and I've been working on my first project. I was wondering how to call a textField I stated from func viewDidLoad in a separate a @objc func. I wanted to load a mailComposeDelegate when I tap a button but in order to do that I need to state 2 textFields which aren't in the same function. How can I do that?

```swift
    func foo() {

        //MARK: SubjectTextField
        
        let subjectTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 10, width: view2.frame.size.width - 100, height: 30))
        
        subjectTextField.placeholder = "Subject"
       
        subjectTextField.borderStyle = .none
        
        subjectTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        subjectTextField.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2517931461, green: 0.2469081879, blue: 0.2469479442, alpha: 1)
        
        subjectTextField.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
        
        subjectTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        view2.addSubview(subjectTextField)
        
        //MARK: Email Text Field
        
        let emailTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 40, width: view2.frame.size.width - 100, height: 30))
        
        
        emailTextField.placeholder = "Email"
        
        emailTextField.borderStyle = .none
        
        emailTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        emailTextField.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2517931461, green: 0.2469081879, blue: 0.2469479442, alpha: 1)
        
        emailTextField.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16)
        
        
        
        view2.addSubview(emailTextField)
        
        //MARK: Scrollable Text View
        let scrollTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 70, y: 70, width: view2.frame.size.width - 100, height: 100))
        
        scrollTextView.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4352585971, green: 0.4353140593, blue: 0.4352396429, alpha: 1)
        scrollTextView.text = "Enter Your Message Here"
        scrollTextView.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 14)
        
        
        

        view2.addSubview(scrollTextView)
        
        //MARK: Create Mail Send Button
        let sendMailButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: 600, width: view2.frame.size.width - 200, height: 50))
        
        sendMailButton.setTitle("SEND", for: .normal)
        sendMailButton.backgroundColor = .black
        sendMailButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        sendMailButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
        sendMailButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        
        sendMailButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendMail), for: .touchUpInside)

        mainScrollView.addSubview(sendMailButton)
        
        
    }
        
    @objc func sendMail(_ button: UIButton) {
     
         // MARK: Email Sender
         
        print("Works")
         let toDestination = ["contact@vaidusi.com"]
         
         let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
         
         mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
         mc.setToRecipients(toDestination)
         mc.setSubject(subjectTextField.text!)
         mc.setMessageBody("Subject: \(subjectTextField.text!) \n\nEmail:\(emailTextField.text!) \n\nMessage: \(scrollTextView.text!)" , isHTML: false)
         
         self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
         
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to create instances for view objects inside the viewDidLoad function. You can have it as a property for the view controller that you are using. After creating the property then initialise those properties inside your viewDidLoad method.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

      var subjectTextField: UITextField!
      var emailTextField: UITextField!
      var scrollTextView: UITextView!
      var sendMailButton: UIButton!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          self.subjectTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 10, width: view2.frame.size.width - 100, height: 30))
          subjectTextField.placeholder = "Subject"
          subjectTextField.borderStyle = .none
          subjectTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
          subjectTextField.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2517931461, green: 0.2469081879, blue: 0.2469479442, alpha: 1)
          subjectTextField.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20) 
          subjectTextField.resignFirstResponder()
          view2.addSubview(subjectTextField)

          //MARK: Email Text Field
          self.emailTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 40, width: view2.frame.size.width - 100, height: 30))
          emailTextField.placeholder = "Email"
          emailTextField.borderStyle = .none
          emailTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
          emailTextField.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2517931461, green: 0.2469081879, blue: 0.2469479442, alpha: 1)
          emailTextField.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16)
          view2.addSubview(emailTextField)

          //MARK: Scrollable Text View
          self.scrollTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 70, y: 70, width: view2.frame.size.width - 100, height: 100))
          scrollTextView.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4352585971, green: 0.4353140593, blue: 0.4352396429, alpha: 1)
          scrollTextView.text = "Enter Your Message Here"
          scrollTextView.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 14)
          view2.addSubview(scrollTextView)

          //MARK: Create Mail Send Button
          self.sendMailButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: 600, width: view2.frame.size.width - 200, height: 50))
           sendMailButton.setTitle("SEND", for: .normal)
           sendMailButton.backgroundColor = .black
           sendMailButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
           sendMailButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
           sendMailButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
           sendMailButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendMail), for: .touchUpInside)
           mainScrollView.addSubview(sendMailButton)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Congrats*** on using Swift.  You'll find that you probably will love Swift, especially when coding for Apple Apps since it's so awesome, simple, and safe!

As further clarification to @Adhith's answer.

Your code snippet does not include the whole class, which in this case is relevant.

If you want your UITextField accessible to more than one function, you must declare it at the class level containing those functions. You would then define / instantiate the variable somewhere, such as viewDidLoad().

```
class someClass {
   var textField: UITextField?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 40, width: view2.frame.size.width - 100, height: 30))
   }

   func anyFunction() {
      // you can access your textfield in any function
      // just make sure that any function that calls it, does so after the
      // variable has been instantiated and/or make the variable optional
      // to keep the code safe
   }

}
```

It appears that you are not using storyboards (IB - Interface Builder).  If you choose to move to that route, you will need to create a 'connector' between the storyboard and the code which is quite simple and will declare the variable automatically for you.

I don't see any layout constraints for your UIViews which may lead to all sorts of layout issues in your app.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Declare your textfield globally so that it can be used all over the class.

"var yourTextField: UITextField!" at the top